# using ion-nav-title makes the back button title doesn't show previous page title

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have two pages now.

```
<ion-view view-title="page1">
```

and

```
<ion-view view-title="page2">
```

When navigate from page1 to page2. The back button title shows properly.

[image]

However, the title of page2 is dynamic, I need to use **ion-nav-title** to make it work

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>{{dynamicTitle}}</ion-nav-title>
```

and I notice that when I using **ion-nav-title** to display page title. The back button title cannot show the title of previous page and return to its default value.

[image]

Is there any thing I can do to make the back button shows properly?

Comment: Did you solve it??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need create a:

```
<ion-nav-title>{{dynamicTitle}}</ion-nav-title>
```

You just need put the scope on your view-title just like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{dynamicTitle}}">
```

Just remember to add your controller on Page2

Follow this example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/LucasES/pen/qaLyPg)